# Serving static files with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to build a simple demo app with embedded Jetty that serves static files from a "html" directory that's a subdirectory of the current working directory.  The idea is that the directory with the demo jar and content can be moved to a new location and still work.

I've tried variations of the following, but I keep getting 404s.

```
ServletContextHandler context = 
                       new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");

context.getInitParams().put(
                       "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.resourceBase", "html");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet()), "/html");

Server jetty = new Server(8080);
jetty.setHandler(context);

jetty.start();
```

**Update:** Here's a solution as documented in the Jetty tutorial.  As mentioned in the correct answer, it uses a `ResourceHandler` instead of a `ServletContextHandler`:

```
    Server server = new Server();
    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

    resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Comment: pom.xml file that works with this: https://code.google.com/p/ram-badger/source/browse/trunk/static-jetty/pom.xml

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with jetty 9...

Comment: if one face same issues with jetty 9 @see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346438/resourcehandler-stop-hosting-files-with-jetty-9-404-not-found-error-works-fin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a [`ResourceHandler`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.7.v20170914/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ResourceHandler.html) instead of [`ServletContextHandler`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.7.v20170914/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html).

Comment: Indeed... http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/handler/ResourceHandler.html

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks guys!  The code is even given in the Jetty tutorial. Doh! http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Configuring_a_File_Server

Comment: you still may want to use `ServletContextHandler` if you need javax.servlet.Filter (for details, please see my comment below)

Comment: Back when Jetty 6 existed, this advice made sense.  Today, with Jetty 9, this  advice is no longer valid.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28419106/775715

Comment: The first link is dead. Anyone knows how to get to that page?

Answer (score 21):

There is an important difference between serving static content using a `ResourceHandler` and using a `DefaultServlet` (with a `ServletContextHandler`).

When a `ResourceHandler` (or a `HandlerList` holding multiple `ResourceHandler` instances) is set as a context handler, it directly processes requests and ignores any registered javax.servlet.Filter instances.

If you need filters, the only way to go about it is using a `ServletContextHandler`, adding filters to it, then adding a `DefaultServlet` and finally, setting the base `Resource`.

The base `Resource` represents a resourceBase path a `ResourceHandler` would be initialised with. If serving static resources from multiple directories, use a `ResourceCollection` (which is still a `Resource`) and initialise it with an array of resourceBase strings:

```
ResourceCollection resourceCollection = new ResourceCollection();
resourceCollection.setResources(getArrayOfResourceBaseDirs());
```

Answer (score 19):

In my small web server I have two files, a `index.html` and a `info.js` locate under `/src/webapp` and I want them to be served from the embedded jetty web server.

This is how I solve the problem with static content.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler();
ctx.setContextPath("/");

DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/webapp/");

ctx.addServlet(holderPwd, "/*");
ctx.addServlet(InfoServiceSocketServlet.class, "/info");

server.setHandler(ctx);
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Could you take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011587/jetty-files-outside-war-and-context

Answer (score 3):

I managed to achieve something similar by adding a mapping for the "css" directory in web.xml. Explicitly telling it to use DefaultServlet:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is `Main.java` file:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setResourceBase("C:/Users/serge.klimkovitch/Documents/images");
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

=====================================

And this is `gradle.build` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'SheetsQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-server', version: '9.4.16.v20190411'

}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'SheetsQuickstart'
    )
  }
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

=====================================

Assuming that the following file exists: `C:\Users\serge.klimkovitch\Documents\images\image.html`

Then, run in Eclipse, and go to `http://localhost:8080/image.html` in your browser to see this file being served.