# How to serve static content with embedded Jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I have tried to serve simple html documents using embedded Jetty, but I keep getting 404 error. Here's my relevant setup

```
ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");
server.setHandler(resource_handler);
```

As I run this from Eclipse and print out the BaseResource, I'll get my project's workspace directory where I have a simple index.html. However if I try the url http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html, I'll get a 404 error - what am I missing?

Comment: I think setResourceBaae attaches you handler to a web resource. In your case it should be '/'.

Comment: If you mean that http://127.0.0.1/ should work, unfortunately it doesn't. gives the same 404 error.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284584/serving-static-files-w-embedded-jetty