# Serve both Thrift/TServlet and static files from same Jetty server

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, thrift, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to serve static files and a Thrift service from the same Jetty server. Up until now I have the following code:

```
val server = new Server();
val connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(4567);
server.addConnector(connector);

val servlet_handler = new ServletContextHandler(server,"/thrift",ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servlet_handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SomeThriftServlet()), "/thrift/*");

val resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

val handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, servlet_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
server.setHandler(handlers);

server.start();
server.join();
```

The static files are served just fine, but the Thrift service keeps giving me 404 errors. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Note**: the code to serve static files was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284584/serving-static-files-w-embedded-jetty), and the 'val' types are taken care of by [project lombok](http://projectlombok.org/), but I left them in there because I think the current code is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you have to wrap the `ResourceHandler` in its own context, and then give the two (or more) contexts their own base path. This is because a ResourceHandler has no base path of it's own.

After this, you can provide the contexts to the server in a `ContextHandlerCollection`, which determines which context to use based on the longest matching path prefix.

```
Server server = new Server();

val connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(4567);
server.addConnector(connector);

val thr = new SomeThriftServlet();

val ct0 = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
ct0.setContextPath("/thr");
ct0.addServlet(new ServletHolder(thr), "/*");

val rsc = new ResourceHandler();
rsc.setDirectoriesListed(true);
rsc.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
rsc.setResourceBase(".");

val ct1 = new ContextHandler();
ct1.setContextPath("/rsc");
ct1.setHandler(rsc);

val contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] {ct0, ct1, new DefaultHandler() });

server.setHandler(contexts);

server.start();
server.join();
```