# Jetty: default servlet context path

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I need to set Servlet (only servlet not handler because of some reasons) to work with files outside war. Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735121/5057736 I found the following solution:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler();
ctx.setContextPath("/");

DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/webapp/");

ctx.addServlet(holderPwd, "/*");//LINE N
ctx.addServlet(InfoServiceSocketServlet.class, "/info");

server.setHandler(ctx);
```

This solutions works and this is what I need. However, it stops working as soon as I change LINE N to `ctx.addServlet(holderPwd, "/foo/*");`. I tried "/foo/","/foo" but result is the same - I get `not found`. Why? How can I make it work with this certain context? I use jetty 9.2.15 because of the same reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `DefaultServlet` is designed to look at the request URI after the `contextPath`.

In your example code when you changed the url-pattern of your servlet from `/` to `/foo/*` the resulting file being looked for on disk is now includes the `/foo/` portion.

In other words, a request URI of `/css/main.css` results in the file (on disk) it expects to find as `./src/webapp/foo/css/main.css`

Your example has a few flaws.  It's not a wise have an empty resource base for your `ServletContextHandler`, as the `ServletContext` itself **needs** access to that configuration value.

You would fix that by removing ...

```java
holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/webapp/");
```

and using [ServletContextHandler.setBaseResource(Resource)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setBaseResource-org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource-) instead ...

```java
ctx.setResourceBase(Resource.newResource(new File("./src/webapp")));
```

This will allow the following `ServletContext` methods (used by countless servlet libraries) to work as well

- `String getRealPath(String path)`
- `URL getResource(String path)`
- `InputStream getResourceAsStream(String path)`
- `Set<String> getResources(String path)`

Finally, to make this setup sane in the `ServletContextHandler`, you'll add the `default` Servlet name, on the "default url-pattern", which happens to be implemented as the `DefaultServlet`.

Like this:

```
// Lastly, the default servlet for root content
// It is important that this is added last.
String defName = "default"; // the important "default" name
ServletHolder holderDef = new ServletHolder(defName, DefaultServlet.class);
holderDef.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
ctx.addServlet(holderDef,"/"); // the servlet spec "default url-pattern"
```

Now, if you *also* have a need to serve static content from request URI `/foo/*` out of a directory not belonging to the webapp, you can do that too.
That will require you to setup another `DefaultServlet` that does not participate in the `ServletContext`.

An example of this setup is ...

```java
package jetty;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class ManyDefaultServlet
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // The filesystem paths we will map
        Path homePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).toPath().toRealPath();
        Path pwdPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toPath().toRealPath();

        // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
        // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setBaseResource(new PathResource(pwdPath));
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Fist, add special pathspec of "/home/" content mapped to the homePath
        ServletHolder holderHome = new ServletHolder("static-home", DefaultServlet.class);
        holderHome.setInitParameter("resourceBase",homePath.toUri().toASCIIString());
        holderHome.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
        // Use request pathInfo, don't calculate from contextPath
        holderHome.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly","true");
        context.addServlet(holderHome,"/foo/*"); // must end in "/*" for pathInfo to work

        // Lastly, the default servlet for root content
        // It is important that this is last.
        String defName = "default"; // the important "default" name
        ServletHolder holderDef = new ServletHolder(defName, DefaultServlet.class);
        holderDef.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
        context.addServlet(holderDef,"/"); // the servlet spec "default url-pattern"

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

This uses a second `DefaultServlet`, using a unique resource base for that `DefaultServlet` only, and mapped to a url-pattern that ends in `/*`.

Finally, the init-parameter for this second `DefaultServlet` is told to use the pathInfo of the Request URI and not split on the contextPath like it normally does.

> For more information on what this whole pathInfo, request URI, contextPath, and url-patterns ending in `/*` are all about, see the [useful answer by @30thh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046620/775715)

This stand alone `DefaultServlet` declaration does not participate in the `ServletContext` and libraries will not be able to see or access the content from that `DefaultServlet` via the `ServletContext` methods.  However all incoming HTTP client requests can request the content easily via that url-pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upvote more then once. Thank you for detailed explanation.