# Jetty - is it safe to use jetty default servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I use jetty 9.3.11 and in my `web.xml` I have the following code to use jetty default servlet for providing static content (images, txt files etc).

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>resourceBase</param-name>
            <param-value>/home/User/data/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Is it safe to use default servlet of jetty this way? I mean - can I be sure that no one will get data from `/home/User/`,`/home/User/temp/`, `/home/` folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use as many `DefaultServlet` instances as you wish.

Just be aware of the behavior of the actual "default" `DefaultServlet` vs the additional ones.  Also what it means for your `ServletContext` and what it can see.

The [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019797/775715) for information.

eg: If you are using a traditional webapp, then the "default" (this is the `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>` instance created by Jetty as part of the Servlet spec) will use the webapp itself as the `Resource Base`.

Any additional `DefaultServlet` instances will not participate in the `ServletContext` rules.  If you have additional `<url-pattern>` segments, you'll want to be aware of the `pathInfoOnly` init-param.

Comment: Can I be sure that no one will get data from /home/User/,/home/User/temp/, /home/ folders if I use DefaultServlet as I described in the question?

Comment: Maybe I am repeating some words, but what I asked in comment is the key point of my question.

Comment: @jimjim2000 yes, you are fine the way you have it in the question.

Comment: @jesse mcconnell Thank you for your comment.