# How do I set a context path with embedded jetty?

Tags: jersey, jetty

I'm banging my head against the wall on this. I wrote a tiny embedded jetty server (jetty 9.4.18, jersey 1.19.4) and I cannot for the life of me get it to respect the context path and my REST services deployed.

I tried setContextPath, but that never worked on ServletContextHandler, so I went with WebAppContext.

This is about as simple as I can get it:

```
Server jettyServer = new Server(9999);

// set up the web app
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/app/");
webapp.setResourceBase("web");

jettyServer.setHandler(webapp);

// add REST service
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = webapp.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/service/*");
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(RestService.class);
resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "org.futureboy.app.server.rest");

try {
    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //jettyServer.stop();
    jettyServer.destroy();
}
```

The static HTML files are served up in the `web` directory, and this works fine if I keep this line as follows:

```
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = webapp.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/service/*");
```

However this means the REST service (which operates under /app/service) does not work. If I swap this line out:

```
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = webapp.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
```

Then the REST service works fine, but now the static HTML content does NOT work fine. So I either get a working static HTML service on `/app/` or a working REST service underneath `/app/service`, but I can't have both. What am I doing wrong? The RestService.java file starts like:

```
@Path("/service")
public class RestService {
```

Any help would be appreciated, for I feel I am stuck on the one-yard line here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want Jersey to serve static content?

That's not the role of a JAX-B server.

What do do ...

1. Switch from `WebAppContext` to `ServletContextHandler` (you don't need the overhead of `WebAppContext` or any of the bytecode scanning or annotation scanning deployment techniques that a full blown `WebAppContext` brings to the table.
2. Prevent Jersey from serving static content.
3. Setup a proper ResourceBase - use a fully qualified path or URI (no relative paths, no partial URIs)
4. Add a `DefaultServlet` on the default url-pattern `"/"` named `"default"`.

Which these changes Jetty will serve static content, from your Resource Base.

Some prior answers/examples of the Jetty side configuration and DefaultServlet usage:

- [Deploying Jetty server via .jar. Why can't I access the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101178/775715)
- [How to get embedded Jetty serving html files from a Jar, not a War](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33836614/775715)
- [Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223103/775715)
- [What is difference between ServletContextHandler.setResourceBase and ResourceHandler.setResourceBase when using Jetty embedded container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419106/775715)
- [Jetty: default servlet context path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019797/775715)
- [Display static HTML file from resources folder in Jetty Serverlet doGet method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277268/775715)

And there's many many answers on how to configure Jersey to not serve static content.

One my favs is the solution provided at ...

- [Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content)

Comment: I basically want this little embedded server to host static html files, some images/javascript/etc, and then the bulk of the project are the REST endpoints. Ideally this would all exist within the same space, but now that you mention it, I suppose I could migrate the static content to Apache and then set up some reverse proxy for the REST.

Comment: What you want to do in Jetty and Jersey is very doable, and quite common.  Just need to configure it properly.