# Serving html file jetty java

Tags: java, html, embedded-jetty

I have this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735121/5030226. It serves the directory but when i open an html file . it throws an internal server error.
please help..

```
     Server server = new Server(8080);
     ServletContextHandler context = new 
     ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    context.setContextPath("/");

    DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
    ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
    holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./src/webapp/");

    context.addServlet(holderPwd, "/*"); 

    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
```

Comment: I can't help you, but I _can_ advise you to post the text of that internal server error.

Comment: thanks, but there is no text,  it just says "HTTP ERROR 500 (which means internal server error)"